# BiqQuery - How to find unique ids overlapping for multiple categories in a column?

Tags: google-bigquery, overlapping, distinct-values

I am very new to BigQuery and standard SQL. I might not be able to figure out the correct approach to solve a problem. Please help me out.

I have a Country Column and a ID column. Example shown below:

**Country** **|** **ID** 
USA | id_1
USA | id_2
USA | id_1
UK  | id_1
UK  | id_1
UK  | id_2
UK  | id_3
AUS | id_3
AUS | id_4
AUS | id_2

**I want a resulting column such as:**

**Output 1:** UNIQUE OVERLAPPING ID values across all the countries

**Country** **|** **Unique_overlapping_ids** 
USA | 2
UK  | 3
AUS | 2

**Output 2:** UNIQUE non-OVERLAPPING ID values across all the countries

**Country** **|** **Non_Unique_overlapping_ids** 
USA | 0
UK  | 0
AUS | 1

I have 88 distinct Countries and over 5M unique IDs

Please help me.
Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Welcome, do you have an example of a query you have tried so far?

Comment: please explain logic behind the expected outputs, just `UNIQUE OVERLAPPING ` and `UNIQUE non-OVERLAPPING ` does not explain all - as it can be interpreted in multiple ways

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant UNIQUE OVERLAPPING would count the unique IDs for Country = USA which repeats in all other Country values and also itself. So if you look at the Main table we see that USA has 2 unique ids which appear across other countries. The same logic applies to Country = UK , Country = AUS. UNIQUE non-OVERLAPPING table would return those unique IDS for Country = USA OR Country = UK or Country = AUS which never appeared across other country values but itself. Does this make sense? I am sorry, Its very confusing but yeah.

Comment: that does not match to presented output1 ... so explain why in output1 usa has 2 and not 1 (only id_2 is shared between all countries - so I would expect to see 1 not 2)

Comment: @BenP i have nothing yet, as i am confused how to approach this.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant correct! nice observation... so if Country = USA has one or more overlapping values across other countries, we categorize group it into output 1. Since id_2 is shared between both USA and UK, we bucket them into an overlapping value...

Comment: so, clarify - should it be 1  or 2 for US based on example you presented? in your question - you using wording `across all the countries` that is confusing part I think. so is it `across all the countries` or `across at least one other country`?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant sorry for being unclear. When Country = USA, id_1 is being shared with 1 or more countries other than USA itself, we classify id_1 to be an overlapping value for USA. When Country = USA, id_2 is being shared with 1 or more countries other than USA itself, we classify id_2 to be an overlapping value for USA. So, USA has 2 overlapping values with other countries

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant **It should be across at least one another country!** Sorry, for not being clear enough.

Comment: sure. got it. now it makes much more sense :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thank you very much!!! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select country, 
  count(distinct if(shared, id, null)) as Unique_overlapping_ids,
  count(distinct if(shared, null, id)) as Unique_non_overlapping_ids
from `project.dataset.table` 
join (
  select id, count(distinct country) > 1 shared
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by id
) using(id)
group by country
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]